# SQL Server self referencing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

Please consider the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST
USE TEST

CREATE TABLE Student
    (
      StudentID INT IDENTITY
                    PRIMARY KEY ,
      FirstName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      LastName NVARCHAR(50)
    )

CREATE TABLE StudentComponent
    (
      StudentComponentID INT IDENTITY
                             PRIMARY KEY ,
      StudentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Student(StudentID) ,
      ComponentName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentRef NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentType NCHAR(2)
    )

CREATE TABLE Component
    (
      ComponentID INT IDENTITY
                      PRIMARY KEY ,
      StudentComponentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.StudentComponent(StudentComponentID) ,
      ComponentName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentRef NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentType NCHAR(2)
    )
```

I have 3 tables

1. Student
2. StudentComponent
3. Component

split out into dimensions

```
CREATE TABLE DimClass
    (ClassDwKey INT,
    ClassName NVARCHAR(50),
    ClassRef NVARCHAR(50))

    CREATE TABLE DimCollege
    (CollegeDwKey INT,
    CollegeName NVARCHAR(50),
    CollegeRef NVARCHAR(50))

    CREATE TABLE DimSubject
    (SubjectDwKey INT,
    SubjectName NVARCHAR(50),
    SubjectRef NVARCHAR(50))

    CREATE TABLE DimStudent
    (StudentDwKey INT,
    StudentName NVARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO 

    CREATE TABLE FactAcademicEvent
    (StudentDwKey int, ClassDwKey int, CollegeDwKey int, SubjectDwKey INT)
```

With relationship in same order between them (Student --> StudentComponent --> Component). I have split the components out into their own dimensions, DimClass, DimCollege, DimSubject (split by componenttype field, = 'CL' for class, 'SU' for subject, 'CO' for college etc. I am trying to load a fact table getting my surrogate keys from my dimensions and produce a row with the following

StudentDwKey (from dimstudent), ClassDwKey, CollegeDwKey, SubjectDwKey.  There is a link between the dimensions and the component table ComponentKey, which links to student through studentcomponent table.

StudentComponent and Component are basically the same, except StudentComponent references students so has more rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: so the componentname and ref equals classname, classref, collegename, collegeref etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT :***

Complete change based on OP's edits and comments.

```
SELECT
  s.StudentID,
  MAX(dim_s.StudentDwKey )   AS StudentDwKey,
  MAX(dim_cl.ClassDwKey  )   AS ClassDwKey,
  MAX(dim_su.SubjectDwKey)   AS SubjectDwKey,
  MAX(dim_co.CollegeDwKey)   AS CollegeDwKey
FROM
  Student            AS s
LEFT JOIN
  StudentComponent   AS sc
    ON  sc.StudentID    = s.StudentID
LEFT JOIN
  dimStudent         AS dim_s
    ON  dim_s.StudentName = s.StudentName  -- or whatever is a reliable join
LEFT JOIN
  dimClass           AS dim_cl
    ON  dim_cl.ClassRef   = sc.ComponentRef
    AND sc.ComponentType  = 'CL'
LEFT JOIN
  dimSubject         AS dim_su
    ON  dim_su.SubjectRef = sc.ComponentRef
    AND su.ComponentType  = 'SU'
LEFT JOIN
  dimCollege         AS dim_co
    ON  dim_co.CollegeRef = sc.ComponentRef
    AND sc.ComponentType  = 'CO'
GROUP BY
  s.StudentID
```

Comment: not quite, so i have students and components split out into dimensions so it will be something like select StudentDwKey, ClassDwKey, CollegeDwKey, SubjectDwKey from DimStudent JOIN DimClass, DimCollege, DimSubject.  There is no relationship between the Dim tables as they are split out from component (in same table) by componenttype. so no relationship between student and dimension tables, the relationship is through studentcomponent...

Comment: @jhowe - I think you're going to have to give some example data and the results you want from that example.  Perhaps making use of www.sqlfiddle.com to make it really clear?

Comment: Hi it'll take me ages to create sample data etc., let me see if i can make it more clear.  If not i'll go on sql fiddle.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i have edited my original question to give more info

Comment: @jhowe - Something like that?

Comment: @jhowe - But...  If a student is associated to multiple classes and multiple subjects, how do you determine what class relates to which subject?  *(Are you sure that you can't create some example data?  Completely fictional to describe the behaviour you need?  Like a Unit-Test?)*

Comment: hi that's another conversation i'm having with the business.  I think you're answer is pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Keep the student details in the Student table (which you have done) and the component details in the Component table (which you have not done) and use the StudentComponent table to link them together. Something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST
USE TEST

CREATE TABLE Student
    (
      StudentID INT IDENTITY
                    PRIMARY KEY ,
      FirstName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      LastName NVARCHAR(50)
    )

CREATE TABLE StudentComponent
    (
      StudentComponentID INT IDENTITY
                             PRIMARY KEY ,
      StudentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Student(StudentID) ,
      ComponentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Component(ComponentID),
    )

CREATE TABLE Component
    (
      ComponentID INT IDENTITY
                      PRIMARY KEY ,
      ComponentName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentRef NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ComponentType NCHAR(2)
    )
```

Comment: hi no these are source tables from a system.  I'm pulling data out of these, splitting into dimensions and trying to insert into a fact table.